How to whitelist a url in supported web addresses for deep linking in an android application?
When I click on the deep link url on my device, my app doesn't open unless I manually go to 'Set as default' for my application & whitelist the url from the 'Supported web addresses' screen.
Supported web addresses screen
I have been trying to implement the deep linking feature on my android application for version 12 & above. I have downloaded the assetlinks.json file from my google play console & uploaded it onto <my_url>/.well-known/ folder.
Then I added the intent filter to my activity like this -
<activity
    android:name=".home.ChangePasswordActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.lib_name"
        android:value="" />

    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data
            android:host="<my_url>"
            android:pathPattern="/password-resets/.*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

How can I automatically get my url whitelisted to enable deep linking in my application without having the user to do that manually? Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

In my case I was not using any keystore to sign my build in dev mode. So I had to get the dev keystore which you can get using this command keytool -list -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore . It asks for a password which is 'android'. So I used the Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256) value in my assetlink.json file & updated it on my url. Once I did that my url got whitelisted by default & my issue was solved.
